# How to get color inside a function that returns a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter, I am trying to do something like **'values/color.xml'** (which is used in android studio) to keep my colors in a file so that i can use them throughout my app easily.
i have stored them in a class but when i use it inside a function that returns widget the colors are not appearing.

Color Values Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorValues {
  static Color highlightColor = const Color(0xFF202d35);
}
```

my function:

```
Container currentPage() {
    return Container(
      height: 20.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text("index"),
      color: ColorValues.highlightColor, //Doesn't work.
      color: Colors.Black, // But this works perfectly.
    );
  }
```

Inside this container widget i will be displaying the index of current page of PageView.
I am using ColorValues.highlightColor inside my build function and it is working fine there. help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: It works, you can pass color value using `ColorValues.highlightColor`. I even tried your code and it worked.

Comment: This should be working normally

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak yes it is working inside my build fucntion but not inside currentPage()

Comment: Why? It should be worked. I tried inside currentPage().

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak i dont know bro. Thanks for your help. I created new project, copied my code from previous one and that worked correctly. deleted the old one :P

Answer (score 0):

rename your color file as `color_value.dart`, not `color.xml`, it will be OK.

Comment: it is a dart file not xml but same issue..

Comment: color: Colors.Black, // Delete this line